# Dash change theme from light to dark

Tags: javascript, css, plotly-dash

I am developing a dash application. I am adding functionality where user can change a theme from light(default bootstrap) to dark(slate bootstrap). I have created 2 folders(light/ and dark/) inside assets folder to hold respective bootstrap.min.css. I am using local css. I have added **dbc.Switch** to change the theme.

```
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
```

How can I proceed further to change css filename in link tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using `ThemeSwitchAIO` from `dash_bootstrap_templates` to Switch themes. You can check it here: https://hellodash.pythonanywhere.com/adding-themes/theme-switch